# Form action attribute link occurring on iPhone and Android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a form. In this form there is an input area. When the user selects the input they are taken to one of three places depending on which device they are using. android - google play store, iphone - itunes store, desktop - itunes web browser. I am able to retrieve the iphone and desktop states, however Android doesn't seem to work on the form tag with an action attribute. The links work fine. Not sure what the issue is. Thanks.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
<div class='main'>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form id="store-link"  >
        <input type='submit'  value='Download'/>        
    </form>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
 </div>
 <div class='footer'>
    <p>footer</p>

 </div>
 </body>
 <script>

 var a = document.getElementById('store-link'); 
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
 a.action = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksmobile.launcher';
 }
 if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
 a.action = 'itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peanuts-storygif-christmas/id1181016912?mt=8';
 }
 else {
 a.action = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peanuts-storygif-christmas/id1181016912?mt=8';
 }

</script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely because on that emulator/phone, you selected "always use Chrome/webbrowser" instead of "Use just once", and so now it opens all google play URLs in the browser instead of prompting you to use either play store or the browser (or only using the play store).

You can clear these preferences in settings.